# JSF 2.0 on Bea Weblogic 10.0

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

Is it possible to run JSF 2.0 on Bea Weblogic 10.0?

If "no", is there a way for a work around?

Comment: @nkm: can you please cut out formatting text as code in your suggested edits? You should only format code as code. For example "JSF" is just text and "FacesContext" is code.

Comment: Well my intention was to just highlight those keywords... Thanks @BalusC for pointing it out, I will take care of this hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2.0 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5. WebLogic 10.x implements Servlet 2.5, so it ought to work.

Comment: But there i always get an error:<br>'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/webapp/ValidatorELTag'